# Inside the AWS custom authorizer, how do I find if the current IAM user is authorized to access that lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, permissions, authorization, amazon-iam

I have delegated my user registation and login to IAM and cognito, and I am storing their API permissing the the Policy Document of the role they are assigned. In that document, I store the ARNs of the Lambda's to `Allow`.

How, inside my custom authorizer, I recieve their `TOKEN` and the API Gateways' `METHOD ARN`.
So how can I go about doing it? I could keep a map to get the lambda function name from the `methodArn` that that would require hardcoding to a level

Comment: Maintain the mapping in an external key/value store such as DynamoDB?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid, I am just wondering if there' s a way to find a users role from his token, then find if that role if permitted to access that lambda

Comment: By "access Lambda", do you mean "invoke a Lambda function"? You generally cannot test for authorization to do something in AWS (unless you also have IAM permissions). Perhaps you could set up a custom event (e.g. with testauth=true) and then simply invoke the Lambda function with that. Either it will fail with an auth error, or it will invoke the Lambda function (in which case the Lambda function detects the testauth=true and treats it as a no-op).

Comment: My lambda assumes a role with IAM permissions.